# Completion and linting in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, completion

I have a problem writing code using the suggestion box in Spyder. Every time I press enter/tab button on the variable/text/library suggestion, it is not what I expect.

For example: I have a variable `karyawan`, when I wrote `print(kar)`, it becomes `prikaryawan`.

Comment: Hi Dika, please try to include more detail: could you include more context/code you have already written?

Comment: It's not only for the code I wrote. When I wrote "import numpy as", the suggestion box will pop up and I chose "numpy as np", when I press enter/tab button it wast not written as "import numpy as np", it wrote "import numpy anumpy as np"

Comment: As far as I can see, it seems that it may have something to do with *where* you press enter/tab—this doesn't entirely make sense still given what you've explained, but it seems that you may be selecting with your cursor in the middle of the word `import nump`<your cursor here>`y as np` or just not finishing the autocomplete. Are there cases where the autocomplete does work? In the `numpy` example, it's adding an 'a'. Is that always the case?

Comment: The latest version of Spyder comes with something called Kite to do code completion and analysis.  If you look on the status bar (all the way at the bottom of the screen), does it say "Kite: ready (no index)" or is there something else there?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.